# How to crop an image after a border (svg)? css

Tags: html, css

I have a picture on the whole screen with a certain height:

```
.background {
    position: relative;
    height: 550px;

    background-image: url("@/assets/images/bg-2.jpg");
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Next comes an svg file (border) inserted via a tag :

```
<div class="background">
      <img src="@/assets/images/border.svg" alt="" width="100%"/>
</div>
```

```
.border {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

More:

[I want to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CogJx.png)

Comment: Please could you make a runnable snippet which shows the problem as I’m finding the description hard to understand. See stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I can think of two ways of achieving this: Either you include the image inside the border SVG, and apply a mask to it (white above the border, black below the border), or you use CSS's ```mask-image``` attribute (After a cursory attempt, this doesn't work in Chrome at all though.). The main problem with the SVG would be that it's not exactly as dynamic as CSS. I guess using a canvas and rendering the image and border together in JS would be another possibility. Either way, the term you're looking for is 'masking'. That might help on it's own.